# $\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty G_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^n G_k)$

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we proved:

> If $G_n\in\mathcal{G}$ and $G_n\uparrow G$, then $G\in\mathcal{G}$ and $\mu(G_n)\rightarrow\mu(G)$.

Think of $\mu$ as a probability measure on $\mathcal{G}$, which is a collection of all limits of increasing sequences of sets in a generic field $\mathcal{F}$.

My Question:
Suppose $A_n\subset\Omega$ and $A_n\uparrow A$. For each $n$, $G_n\in\mathcal{G}$ and $A_n\subset G_n$. Why is the below valid?

$$\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty G_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^n G_k).$$

Reference:
$\textit{Probability and Measure Theory}$ (Robert B. Ash and Catherine A. Doleans-Dade), Harcourt/Academic Press, 1999.

Comment: You can define $B_n$ as a union of the $G_i$ sets, then apply the general fact about increasing sets to $B_n$. The fact about $G_n$ that you state has nothing to do with $A_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have proved:

> If $G_n\in\mathcal{G}$ and $G_n\uparrow G$, then $G\in\mathcal{G}$ and $\mu(G_n)\rightarrow\mu(G)$.

We want to prove:

> If $G_n\in\mathcal{G}$, then$$\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty G_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^n G_k).$$

Let $S_n=\bigcup_{k=1}^n G_k$ and $S=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty G_n$. Then $S_n\uparrow S$. Hence $\mu(S_n)\rightarrow\mu(S)$, i.e. $$\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty G_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^n G_k).$$